# Different Content Length between C# and Java

Tags: java, httpwebrequest

I am trying to read a upload file from browser, then write to a remote server. But I found that the request.getheader("content-length") is different from the actual length of request.getInputStream() in JAVA. But Request.Header["Content-Length"] is same as the actual length of  Request.InputStream in C#.

Could anyone try to explain the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the situations are comparable? One pitfall might be the possibility of zipped content.
Another one might be the character encoding if one implementation counts the characters and the other one counts the bytes sent over the connection.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. After all, we found that there's a mistake when we try to read 1024 length to a buffer byte[] array. The method readByte in Java, only fill the fisrt some byte but not clear the others to '\0'. So the bytes we write that to the remote stream is longer than "Content-Length".